# How can I validate that my ASP.NET session data can be serialized correctly?

Tags: asp.net, session, serialization

I am trying to switch from saving session data "InProc" to "StateServer".

To do that, I have marked a bunch of classes as [Serializable] and rewritten some classes that could not be serialized before, and marked some values that should not be serialized as [NonSerialized].

Now my problem is that instead of getting a compile-time error, an exception or any other indication of a problem from the framework, I get sessions back where some of the values stored are changed to null-values, either in the session itself or inside the objects contained in the session.

Why is there no indication of an error?

What causes the null-values?

How can I detect that the serialization of the session was correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need some unit tests to confirm your serialization is working correctly.

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeClass {
    public string SomeValue1;
    public string SomeValue2;
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var value1 = new SomeClass() { SomeValue1 = "Hello", SomeValue2 = "World" };
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(ms, value1);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var value2 = (SomeClass)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        Debug.Assert(value1.SomeValue1 == value2.SomeValue1);
        Debug.Assert(value1.SomeValue2 == value2.SomeValue2);
    }
}
```